# How to solve the error Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key

Please suggest me how to solve the error How to solve the error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "MyForeignKeyName". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.MyTable", column 'IMyColumn'.

Comment: Try to See this below link  i hope your problem is solved

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865873/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constrain

Comment: What does your table look like (`CREATE TABLE` DDL, as well as constraint DDL), and what was your exact statement that you tried to execute, resulting in the error?

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to make foreign key and your child table already have some data that does not match with your parent table, you will get this error message.

**For Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyParent(Job_id int PRIMARY KEY,Job_Name Varchar(50));

INSERT INTO MyParent Values(1,'CEO');
INSERT INTO MyParent Values(2,'Business Manager');
INSERT INTO MyParent Values(3,'DBA');

CREATE TABLE MyChild(Emp_id int,Emp_Name Varchar(50),Job_Id int)

INSERT INTO MyChild Values(1,'Lavanya',1);
INSERT INTO MyChild Values(1,'JP Chauhan',3);
INSERT INTO MyChild Values(1,'Rakesh',5);
```

See the last record of MyChild table that has value in Job_Id is 5, which is not in MyParent table.

If you try to make foreign key relation like:

```
ALTER TABLE MyChild
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_My_foreignKey FOREIGN KEY(Job_Id)REFERENCES MyParent(Job_Id);
```

The error message you will get:

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_My_foreignKey". The conflict occurred in database "mydatabase", table "dbo.MyParent", column 'Job_id'.

Comment: Make sure first, you have no any such records in your child table and take care of that record otherwise it will conflict the constraint.